# Trigger select doesn't work with trigger event

Tags: javascript, jquery

To trigger input I can use focus(), but it doesn't work for select element. I tried trigger('change'), nothing happened. Not sure what is wrong.

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/r8ca2jgr/

```
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<button>trigger</button>


$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('select').trigger('change');
  })
});
```

Comment: [Works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/r8ca2jgr/1/) if you bind the `change` event on `<select>`.

Comment: what do dou want to do, do you want the dropdown to popout on the button click

Answer (score 0):

Add a type for the button element:

```
<button type="button">trigger</button>
```

By default the type of the button is "submit" so your form will be submitted and you notice nothing for trigger change.

Comment: You have not enclosed in a form. And I hope OP has wrapped with the form in his code.

Comment: @Jennifer What? You should check.